# Why doesn't my downloaded file appear in the Download folder?

Tags: samsung, facebook

I've downloaded a Powerpoint presentation of the Facebook mobile app and when I go to the downloads folder and search up the name of the file, it doesn't appear. It just says "No results found. I use a Samsung A6.

[image: IMG:]
[image: IMG:]

Comment: What happens when you click on  the notification? It should open the file, then you could check the file location on the your PowerPoint associated app. Or check the settings of Facebook if the download location is the Download folder

Comment: If you are able to open the downloaded file(s) for example with adobe acrobat reader for PDF files, you can check the details/information about them from the app and obtain the info on their location(s).

Comment: I came here with the same issue. Facebook downloaded a pdf, I can open it in Adobe reader. wanted to share it but it's not in my download folder and reader has no details option and a search for the file results in nothing (at least from my downloads folder)